Devant que de lui parler
De « La Symphonie pastorale » d'André Gide (1919) :

Mais devant que de lui parler je me sentis le cœur si gonflé et par des sentiments si troublés que je ne savais ou n'osais aborder le sujet qui me tourmentait.

Mon hypothèse est que ce que est l'équivalent de quoi ou ce que, ce qui donnerait quelque chose comme : « Devant [i.e., face à] ce dont je devais lui parler. »
Mais Frank dans le chat est d'opinion que la phrase veut dire : « Avant de lui parler. »

Quel en est le sens au juste ?
Est-ce que cette tournure existe toujours ? Serait-elle très littéraire ?


Devant que de est un équivalent littéraire d'avant de.

TLFi
− Locution conjonctive

Devant que de + infinitif. Avant de :
Donc, devant que de quitter la pension Keller pour rentrer à l'école Alsacienne, je cherchai quelque moyen subtil de marquer à M. Jacob le souvenir ému que je gardais de ses bons soins. Gide, Si le grain ne meurt, 1924, p. 496.


La citation est aussi d'André Gide.
Aussi : Wiktionary.

Il y a d'autres exemples que dans Gide? Il semble être le spécialiste de ce genre de tournure.

So often I forget that even the most basic particles can be looked up in unusual combinations....!

What is original with Gide is using devant that more usually relate to space instead of avant that usually relate to time. The expression avant que de, still very literary, is much more common than devant que de.

@jlliagre so the Gidean car has le moteur au devant instead of à l'avant?

I wonder how he'd denote his time at the Ecole alsacienne. Derrière que de quitter la pension Keller I'll wager.

@jlliagre That is a very good point. Had he used avant que de, I would definitely have figured out the intended meaning, parsing the role of que de as a comparative connector similar to e.g. plutôt que de + [verb phrase]. Now that you've made the connection, I see that it was the semantic contribution of devant, which I associate not only with space but with the figuratively spacial "facing up to" (devant l'horreur, devant l'incompréhensible), that made it hard for me.
